# res.redirect(url) only working intermittently

Tags: node.js, express, response.redirect

I have an application where there are a couple of weird issues.

*** UPDATED BELOW ***

We're using Express/Node with Postgres DB. When I start both servers up, everything works fine, as expected. When I open up Chrome and start to input the URL:port, we immediately get log information before ever pushing the Enter key. It's here where everything returns the expected values. When I press enter, it redirects to an /auth page, grabs a token and returns it, but this is where it weirds out:

Typically, when it's a fresh server restart, it will get down to the `res.redirect(url)` call and then it will **stop**. It doesn't reach back to the database and grab all the requisite JSON data it should be pulling. If I repeat the process two (or three or four...) more times, it will grab all the information and allow me to update my user record. Additionally, if I stop/restart the servers, enter URL and press enter and then refresh the page, everything works as expected.

*** I forgot to mention that this problem didn't rear its head until we started making a call to get the token. If I take out the code to retrieve the token, I don't have this problem, leading me to think it's a timing-based issue, but I can't find where the problem is after a long time testing. ***

Is there any known issue as to why the redirect will sometimes work and other times not?

Involved scripts below:

**home.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(GET_TOKEN) });
router.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
    auth_code = req.query.code
    userJson = {}
    userJson.full_name = 'John Doe'
    userJson.email = 'johndoe@example.com'
    userJson.emp_id = 12345678
    userJson.app_id = 'doejohn'
    userJson.is_admin = true
    req.session.user = userJson
    var url = '/reg'
    if (!auth_code || auth_code === undefined) {
        url = '/'
    }
    console.log("Attempting redirect")
    res.redirect(url) });
```

**registration.js**

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    userJson = req.session.user
    userJson.user_id = ""
    userJson.user_name_cd = ""
    userJson.user_password = ""
    userJson.existing_user = false
    params = [userJson.app_id]
    var url = 'user/' + params + '/info'
    exstngRegs = await util.httpGet('exstngRegs', url)
    rolecode = 'A'
    userJson.rolecode = rolecode
    user_name_cd = ''
    button_name = 'Register'
    view_name = 'registration'
    if (JSON.stringify(exstngRegs) != '[]') {
        userJson.existing_user = true
        button_name = 'Update Registration'
        userJson.user_id = exstngRegs[0].user_id
        user_name_cd = 'readonly'
        if (!userJson.is_deleted) {
            view_name = 'regexists'
        } else {
            view_name = 'registration'
            button_name = 'Register'
        }
        userJson.user_name_cd = user_name_cd
        userJson.button_name = button_name
        util.handleView(res, constants.registration_title, constants.registration_menu, view_name, userJson) });
```

What ends up happening on a failure is I'll get a **ReferenceError** on some userJson information (usually, but not always, on the ** *user_id* ** (which is an input typed in at user registration and is verified **in** the database and tied to the correct user).

Just boggling my mind why it would show me a console log indicating that it's attempting a redirect, but not moving on from there and going to the registration.js file. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE FOLLOWS**

Looking more at this code, I think I see what's happening, but not sure how to fix it. When I begin typing my URL, all the data loads (console logging shows connection with the database and I have logs displaying the web app is running as expected)--all this happens and is shown in the terminal **BEFORE** I press the `Enter` key. Essentially, everything is good to go RIGHT NOW. But, when I press the `Enter` key to confirm that, yes, I want to go to this web page, it runs a GET /, which redirects to the /auth page and runs JUST that code up to, but not including, the `res.redirect(url)`.

Does anyone know a fix for this, or how to enforce that res.redirect(url) to run? I tried creating a simple function that runs prior to it and throwing that redirect in there, but no dice. Help!

Comment: The first file seems to be missing the end of it here.

Comment: On /auth route add `});` after `res.redirect(url)`

Comment: Sorry; yes. I added that just now, but that wasn't the cause of my conflict. Sorry, I was copying all that code and rewriting from another screen as I was not able to copy/paste.

Comment: After running through the code, I'm seeing something else now that may help answer this question, though I can't find why:

When the code *works* it will run in the following order:
```- /auth page
- /auth page (again)
- /registration page```

When it *does not* work, it will go in this order:
```- /auth page
- /registration page
- /auth page```