# Website comes up as soon as I start typing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, web

I have an application in Node/Express that is exhibiting some strange (to me, at least) behavior. I am not sure why this happens, but as soon as I begin typing in the URL, the web page instantly comes up. All the logs start populating data and I have my home screen. This is on a local instance for now as I'm still trying to work out bugs related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429679/res-redirecturl-only-working-intermittently?noredirect=1#comment115679476_65429679). I believe these two may be inter-related, but I can't find any data online; perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms, but the long and the short of it is this:

I'm connected to a VM (CentOS7) and everything is run through AWS. I type in my IP:PORT (e.g. `12.34.56.78:9999`). As SOON as I type the '1' in the URL, all the logs fire, running through all the scripts. Since I'm at my home page, I hit 'Enter' and is SUPPOSED to go through a redirect to an authorization page (e.g. `12.34.56.78:9999/auth`). At that point we're running into my original post, identified above, but this question is simply an attempt to understand why my web page is being shown before I ever 'finish' the call by hitting the 'Enter' key. Is this normal behavior when an application is being accessed locally?

Comment: Which browser/OS combination are you using?

Comment: We are using Chrome with CentOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Because your browser is "smart" and guesses that you want to open that website and will therefore load it before you complete the url. That of course only happens if you have previously visited that site, otherwise the browser does not know the url yet. What logic the browser internally uses for this decision depends mostly on the browser and its settings, wether it factors in how recently you visited it or how often, or ...

If you actually want to browse that website when you finish typing the browser has already loaded the page and can instantly display it instead of now loading it and letting you wait a couple of seconds. If you decide you want to go to 123.com instead the browser simply discards the preloaded page and continues as normal.

Comment: If there a specific browser or browser/setting combination that you know does this pre-fetch? I don't see it by default in any of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari.

Comment: This is what confuses me, @luk2302. If I, for example, type `espn.com` in my URL, yes, it'll realize I want to go to ESPN and auto-populate the URL with that suggestion--but it stops there. It doesn't **LOAD** ESPN at that point, and does not do that until I press the `Enter` key. It doesn't do it for any other web pages; it's gotta be something with the script, I'd think.